# "Export" machine learning model from R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I can build and implement classic ML models on traditional training/test sets in R, but what if a partner wants to get this model in order to implement his own (any kind of) system? Saving and sending the R-model structure doesn't help, of course; and figuring out the prediction mechanism doesn't work in many (black box) cases neither. So how to generalize and utilize the model's learned rules?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096520/compile-r-script-into-standalone-exe-file

Comment: Adding to @AchimZeleis' nice answer (+1), take a look at [this excellent blog post](http://things-about-r.tumblr.com/post/37861967022/predictive-modeling-using-r-and-the-openscoring-engine) on implementing an `R`-based _PMML_ solution.

Answer (score 5):

One way to share models between the software that does the actual model fitting and the software that is used to do the predictions is the Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML). This is an XML-based standard maintained by the [Data Mining Group](http://www.dmg.org/) consortium. It allows to deploy models to other applications, to the cloud, or database systems. So if the software that your partner wants to is PMML-compliant, then you can employ the [pmml](http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pmml) package to export your models from R. Of course, there are more machine learning models implemented in R than supported by the PMML standard or the `pmml` R package but there is quite a range of supported models. The `pmml` package is also employed by the `rattle` data mining GUI in R.